# zsh: command not found: foo

Tags: visual-studio-code, command-line, vagrantfile

I'm learning the power of Vagrant, and I have stumbled upon this problem. I am trying to create a text named foo.txt with the text "foo" inside of it.

What I type into the terminal is this:

- user@User-MBP data % "foo" > foo.txt

Terminal says:

- zsh: command not found: foo

Has anyone encountered this? Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can't just throw a string at the file like that. You need to use a program like `echo` to throw it for you.

```
echo "foo" > foo.txt
```

To be a little more clear about why, run `man echo`.

The `echo` program "writes arguments to the standard output". Whatever argument you give it (i.e. "foo") it will write to standard output.

You follow that with the `>` operator which "redirects standard output". Read about that [here](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).

You then specify a file to "catch" the redirected standard output (i.e. foo.txt) which you already did just fine.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for taking the time to help me!